# wget Script : %0D at the end of filename

Tags: linux, bash, script, wget

I have a bash script who loop on the wget command. But I don't know why I have a %0D at the end of all of the filenames except the first.

```
for var in "${array[@]}"
do
    wget -P output_folder "${var}"
done
```

Why I have this ? How to resolve this ?

Comment: What URLs are you using?

Comment: If the URL Has it in then it should be there (though %0D might be a bit strange or unusual in a URL. Sometimes URLs write funny characters in with a percentage followed by the character's utf-16 code.  So sometimes a "literal" ampersand character might be or would be, written in with its utf-16 code.

Comment: I am using server's url with a lot of characters (tokens etc...). I don't saw for the moment any modulo in the url. Meanwhile, I stock the url in a file and I launch the command `wget -i`.

Comment: @Kaayo25 the 0D character is often found in windows text files as it's one of the new line characters. So try converting the file from windows line separators to unix line endings, then feed it to wget. There are other things you could try too, like having the file contain just the problem URL, then do you can xxd filename  and look at the hex of the file, and cat the file and look at the file(that way with xxd, will show hex and corresponding text). And you'll just understand better what is going on. Does it happen with every URL in the file or just one?

Comment: also i've heard that the old mac os used to use 0d as the new line character/

Comment: notepad++ has an option to convert from windows line separators to unix line endings. And if you are using a hex editor or xxd then you can see what it has done. You may also be able to find commands like dos2unix or unix2dos that let you convert between \r\n and \n i.e. between windows line separators and unix line endings.

Comment: It's happen with all url. I am note on notepad++, I code the script with nano on debian 8. I will test with xxd

Answer (score 0):

Try the --restrict-file-names option

wget --restrict-file-names=unix

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining it

Comment: Welcome to Super User. While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.